# Does concatenating in a StringBuilder append() statement take a different amount of execution time than using two append() statements?

Tags: java, string, append, concatenation, stringbuilder

I was wondering the execution speed changes if a programmer concatenates inside a Stringbuilder append() statement, or just uses two append statements instead of one.

I am asking this question to help me figure out why we use the StringBuilder class at all when we can just concatenate.

**Concatenation Example:**

```
public class MCVE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myArray = {"Some", "stuff", "to", "append", "using", "the",
                "StringBuilder", "class's", "append()", "method"};

        StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();

        for(String s: myArray) {
            stringBuild.append(s + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

**Double-Append() Example:**

```
public class MCVE {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] myArray = {"Some", "stuff", "to", "append", "using", "the",
                "StringBuilder", "class's", "append()", "method"};

        StringBuilder stringBuild = new StringBuilder();

        for(String s: myArray) {
            stringBuild.append(s);
            stringBuild.append(" ");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `stringBuild.append(s);
            stringBuild.append(" ");` could be simplified to ` `stringBuild.append(s).append(" ");`, btw you could do that entire logic with `String.join(" ", myArray);`

Comment: @Aomine I didn't know that, thanks!

Comment: @Aomine goes straight to the heart of the issue. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In theory, yes, the concatenation version will take longer, because under the covers it creates a whole new `StringBuilder`, appends `s`, appends `" "`, and then uses `toString` to create(!) a string for that to pass to the `append` you coded. (That's what the compiler does. To know about your *specific* situation, you'd need to test [a benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) representative of your actual code. After all, the JIT will get involved if it's a hotspot at runtime.)

Of course, you probably won't notice. But still, if you're already using `StringBuilder`, use it (by doing `append` twice instead). :-)

---

(The first paragraph above *wouldn't* be true if they were both string literals, e.g. `"foo" + "bar"`. The compiler does that concatenation.)

Comment: Thank you! So I guess we just use StringBuilder to avoid creating StringBuilder objects over and over again when we concatenate Strings more than once?

Comment: @LuminousNutria - Yes, in situations where performance (speed and memory consumption) is more important than code clarity. Which is rarely, but sometimes. But if this comes up a lot, you might see if there's some kind of built-and-tested templating engine or library you could use instead.

Comment: it seems likely that the two stringbuilder operations would be quicker than the concatenation but why not test it? Use System.nanoTime() to see how long it takes to run your for loop a large number of times.

Comment: @stegzzz - Or [a thorough benchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java). :-) After all, the above is correct in terms of the bytecode created by the compiler, but the JIT will get involved if it's a hotspot in the code.